# Reverse numbering for a list in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to create a reverse list using css/html for eg

```
5. Red
4. Green
3. Blue
2. Yellow
1. Black
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by using simple reserve attribute with HTML go to following link for complete explanation

```
<ol reversed>  
    <li>Red</li>  
    <li>Green</li>  
    <li>Blue</li>  
    <li>Yellow</li>  
    <li>Black</li>  
</ol>
```

see fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/sYSEJ/

Comment: Instead of having only a link, you should put the codes into your answer as well.

Comment: as he specified he is new to coding i thought whole explanation will be helpful. Instead of just codes

Comment: you can still have the link to the full explanation, but in general on stackoverflow you should also provide a snippet showing the solution.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but [you can make it better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.

Comment: @amitmishra I did it for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ol reversed="reversed">
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Green</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Black</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 CR has the `reversed` attribute for such purposes, but it’s a wrong solution, because it makes the rendering browser-dependent. It has been slowly implemented in browsers, and e.g. IE does not support it even in version 10. Moreover, it is (arguably) presentational, and adding new presentational attributes to HTML is against the general trend.

Some alternatives:

1. Add `value` attribute to each `li` element. This can be done when generating the page server-side, or with client-side JavaScript.
2. Use a `ul` element, suppress bullets (`list-style-type: none`), and put numbers into `li` content (possibly programmatically, as above). Why `ul` and not `ol`? Because you don’t want double numbering when CSS is off.
3. As above, but use generated content and a counter in CSS.

Comment: `value` attribute is deprecated. and also `reverse` attribute doesn't support opera browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/ol#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I need to correct myself, `value` attribute is reintroduced in HTML5 again. So it supports in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reversed` attribute of `ol` tag. But it [doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/ol#Browser_compatibility) IE and opera.

- If you want a cross-browser support solution, then you need to look in to javascript.
- Or else, why not just use other elements like `div` or `span` and assign the numbers dynamically using javascript?

There are many alternatives, if you opt javascript instead of going strictly with HTML and CSS.

An example: (*using javascript*)

```
<ol id="olTag">..............
```

---

```
ChangeNumbering();    
function ChangeNumbering() {
    var list = document.getElementById("olTag");
    var liTags = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var length = liTags.length;
    for (var i = length; i > 0; i--) {
        liTags[length - i].value = i;
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sYSEJ/4/)**

***Side Note***: `Value` attribute of `li` tag was deprecated in HTML4, but again [re-introduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li#value) in HTML5. So, ofcourse it remains  [cross-browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do this, but you need to specify the starting value. This is still easier than filling in the `value` attribute on each list element.

For example with 4 list items do:

```
ol {
  counter-reset: num 5;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before {
  counter-increment: num -1;
  content: counters(num, ".") " ";
}
```

This works in IE8 and up.